# Firebase redirects http to https with 307 code (Temporarily Moved), which is bad as per SEO. How to configure it to use 301 code (Permanently Moved)

Tags: seo, redirects, 301-redirect, firebase

My website is hosted with Firebase. It offers https out of the box. When a user hits http://example.com, it redirects to https://example.com with 307 code (Temporarily Moved). As per various SEO guidelines, this is not good practice. How to configure firebase to use 301 (Permanently Moved)?

Comment: Unless your site used to be on HTTP (not HTTPS) and it has lots of external links that point to HTTP, the type of redirect isn't going to matter much at all for SEO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just tested this out on a Firebase Hosting site and (after disabling my browser extensions) I got a 301 redirect, not a 307.

What are you using to inspect the status code? Web browsers sometimes report a 307 status code when there's an internal redirect within the browser itself before it sends the request.

Chrome for example calls this kind of pre-request redirect a `307 Internal Redirect`, but in actuality there is no "real" HTTP request or status code. A redirect of this sort is usually caused by HSTS on the server. HSTS is a security feature that Firebase Hosting uses.

In any case, a `307 internal redirect` cannot affect SEO because it happens within the browser itself. So unless you are getting some other kind of 307, it's nothing to worry about.

Comment: Good answer.I use httpstatus.io to check redirects ;)

Comment: I use screaming frog to inspect the url. When I hit non-www url, it show redirection with 307. The status column states "HSTS Policy".  Take a look at this screenshot. https://ibb.co/QXLCJ1T

Comment: @KaushalB Awesome. The fact that it says "HSTS Policy" means you are good to go for SEO!